# Facebook Graph API changed results from /posts today?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I have an iOS app that has been fetching the user's Facebook status updates and location checkins using "/me/posts" for several months. After today's "breaking changes" update, "/me/posts" only returns recent "Like"s. It looks like "/me/statuses" and "/me/checkins" are the new proper places to check for these things. I guess that makes sense, but I saw no documentation anywhere describing these changes or saying that they would happen today. The original documentation about what is specifically returned from the graph API also seems pretty slim.

So my questions are: is this an official change to the API? Where was it specified? Where should I look so I can stay on top of these things and not have my app break for hundreds of users?

Perhaps more importantly: are "/me/statuses" and "/me/checkins" the new proper ways to get this information? Or is there something else?

Comment: I've attempted to answer you question, but you ask a lot of questions here.  Try to limit yourself to one clear, concise question per post (this is called out by SO posting guidelines).

Comment: Yes sorry about that. A bit frustrated today!

Comment: Did the permissions associated with your access token change at all? what does a call to `/me/permissions` show?

Comment: For the app itself, '/me/permissions' shows `installed`, `user_checkins` and `user_status` all '1'. '/me/posts' shows nothing now as my app. As API Explorer, '/me/posts' gives me recent likes, but that's it. When I first set up this code a few months ago, '/me/posts' was giving me status updates, location checkins, likes, and wall posts. In trying to fix this, I have changed the permissions with my app, so it's possible something has changed - but it's suspicious that it was the same day as FB's "breaking changes" launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always good to keep a (sharp) eye on the [Developer Roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).  These types of changes happen often, but FB *usually* does a good job of calling them out ahead of time.  You've answered your own question as far as whether or not it's an "official" change - you're seeing it in the wild - insofar as how Facebook works, it's official.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Graph API Explorer. It could be an access token issue.

FYI: I see a similar issue with my application, and I am able retrieve the posts only when I use the Graph API Explorer and the token I get from there.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found where some of the problems lived. In the app profile in Facebook, pick "Edit Settings" and then go to "Advanced" where you'll see a section called "Migrations". This is mostly switches to show compatibility for various "breaking changes" updates, but it also includes an option for "Include Checkins with Statuses".

Now I know where to look, things are making a bit more sense.